# The “more »” link is not doing anything different

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was passing here and there on Stack Overflow and when I reached [the Android tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms), on the right-hand side, it looks like this on desktop:

[image: Android tag synonyms — five synonyms are listed, followed by a “more »” link]

I clicked on the “more »” link at the bottom and it does not do anything other than reload the page. I believe it is a bug (there are 7 synonyms for the Android tag) or a logical error that needs an `if` statement.

Comment: no need to use all these tags in your question ... it's either a dicussion OR a feature-request OR a bug ... we cannot discuss about requesting a bug as a feature

Comment: Correct me edit it @TemaniAfif

Comment: @TemaniAfif But maybe he wanted a feature-request for being able to discuss bugs?

Comment: I do not have enough attention on my question what should I do?@TemaniAfif

Comment: I don't see this as a bug. The link leads to the synonyms page, which lists all seven. That you clicking the link when *already* on the synonym page doesn't matter here, that same list and link is present on more tag-related pages, it is a shared piece of content. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers for example. Or https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info (where the layout is slightly different, but it's the same content).

Comment: Okay I got you, but for one way or another, it is misleading. We always expect a `more»` button in the web should load stuffs below it as a list. It always common when you find a `more` or `next` button then we expect to show more content. So in this case according to your comment, that side navigation should not even be there on the same page which has the full list of synonyms. And clicking it is even more useless. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Perhaps; it's not a great UI. But it is not a *bug*, per se.

Comment: Yeah its not a bug, it is also a great UI but not a good UX.@MartijnPieters